# Telegram bot ( how to edit data by inline_message_id)?

Tags: telegram-bot

I try to make a telegram bot, in which you can create a vote and send this to someone else for a response.When the user clicks on a button for changing results we got this changes in all chats in which this voting. As I found out, we can edit the data by chatID and message id. How to change data only in chat in which this data is?

```
await bot.editMessageText(`<b>${updatedResponse.question}</b>\n\n${message}`, {
                inline_message_id: inline_message_id,
                parse_mode: 'HTML',
                reply_markup: {
                    inline_keyboard: arrayOfAnswers
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [inline feedback](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#collecting-feedback), and you will receive [ChosenInlineResult](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult) update, which including `inline_message_id`.